# I would like to store the results of a query, then compare those results to the next set. Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, compare, average

```
//This is my query
SELECT bline_id, ROUND(Avg(flow),3) avg  
FROM   (SELECT id, bline_id, flow, date, CASE 
             WHEN @previous IS NULL 
               OR @previous = bline_id THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
             ELSE @rownum := 1 
           end rn, 
           @previous := bline_id 
    FROM   blf, 
           (SELECT @rownum := 0, 
                   @previous := NULL) t 
    WHERE bline_id > 0 and bline_id < 31
    ORDER  BY bline_id, 
              date DESC, 
              id) t 
  WHERE  rn < 11
  GROUP  BY bline_id
```

This query takes the average of the last 10 records. I would like to be able to save these results back into the db, and compare them to the next group of 10 when a new record is added.

The end result I am looking for is to be able to tell if there is a change in the average by +or- 2%.
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a table with the following fields:

id, bline_id, avg, timestamp

Every time you add a record, insert the results of your query above into this table.

You can then compare the latest record in this table with the previous one.

Comment: That is what I would like to do but I am not sure how to go about INSERTing the query result into the new table?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! Getting closer, I got the INSERT INTO a new table accomplished!